# Copying data between excel workbooks really slow

Tags: excel, performance, delphi

Delphi XE6, Excel 2013. Win 8.1

I am using Delphi to copy data between two workbooks (the end result being that I need a new .xlsx file, with a subset of the data.  I then save the new workbook.)  Copying 10 rows takes between 18 and 19 seconds....My test copies the same row...  Timing is when calling directly (as opposed to running within the Delphi debugger.

```
 StartingWorkBook := XLApp.ActiveWorkbook;
 NewWorkbook := XLApp.WorkBooks.Add(EmptyParam, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT);

 for j := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    StartingWorkbook.Sheets[1].Range['A6', 'A6'].EntireRow.Copy(NewWorkBook.Sheets[1].Range['A12','A12'].EntireRow;         
  end;
```

Both StartingWorkbook and NewWorkbook are defined as OleVariants.

What can I do to speed things up?  This is incredibly slow.  I realize that OleVariants are not the fastest, but almost 2 seconds to copy each row is ridiculous.

ADDITIONAL DATA POINT:
When exiting Excel, I was getting an error message "The picture is too large and will be truncated."  Upon investigating that, it appears that there is another program monopolizing the Clipboard.  When I run this same code on another computer, it runs fine... 108 ms.  I uninstalled TeamViewer (which is a known culprit) but still have not identified the problem...

Thanks to those who have tried to help.  This has been a frustrating problem...

Comment: Why are you copying the entire row? Do you have every cell populated from 'A1' through `XFD1` (Excel 2013) or whatever the furthest right cell is in your Excel version? Copy just the range of cells you actually need. You're doing the equivalent of "I need all the numbers between one hundred and one trillion that end with the digit 9. I know: I'll generate them all to an big disk file, and then read that disk file back, look at the number on each line, and see if it ends with '9'. If it does, I'll write it to another file."

Comment: Also, why are you even doing it row by row? You can select the entire range and copy it in one operation.

Comment: I tried specifying a specific range, for example, copy A6..T6 to another workbook, A12..T12, but it did not help performance.   As to the WHY row by row, I am trying to copy specific rows, but I cannot guarantee that they are sorted.  For example, I want to copy all rows where a specific column is 'XYZ', but that column is not sorted...

Comment: Copying an entire range is considerably faster, so why you saw no performance difference is strange. As far as "where a specific column is 'XYZ', so I do all of the rows in their entirety", see my first comment starting with *You're doing the equivalent of*.

Comment: When I say no performance improvements, it went from 18.6 seconds to 18.2 seconds...

Comment: Your results seem very wrong. IMO, the performance difference is considerably greater, which makes me think that your other code was just as wrong as this code. I can't say for certain that it was wrong, because I can't see it, but your performance numbers are way off.

Comment: Here is a reference of someone else running into the problem... http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/467792-picture-too-large-will-truncated.html   ...  mentioned at bottom of page.  I am going to try a UNION Range operation to see if that helps...

Comment: Can you provide a sample file or is everybody able to reproduce this with an empty Excel file?

Comment: I just tested (quickly) copying a range from 'A1:F11' and putting it into a new Workbook at range 'B1', measuring from just before selecting the origin range to just after assigning to the destination range to ensure that connecting to Excel itself was excluded, and it was so quick that `TStopWatchElapsedMilliseconds` is still zero. (I'll be happy to post the code.)

Comment: Extended the test to copy `A1:X44` to have a larger range, and it took 149ms, which is still just over a 10th of a second. You really have to narrow the number of cells per row you're copying; that has to be the issue, and if you insist you can't do so then you have to live with the performance hit you receive as a result.

Comment: @@Ken,  Can you loop the copy and do it 10 times, see if there is any type of other issue?  As additional info, I am using AddIn Express, so this is a plug-in routine for Excel.

Comment: There's no point in copying the same range over the same range 10 times, so your problem is making even less sense. Why would you do that? I can't help with AddIn Express, and your question should indicate you're writing an Excel addin. I have code that directly automates Excel from a Delphi application using late binding that is extremely performant. I can't help with intentionally invented performance slowdowns using a library I don't have, I'm afraid.

Comment: When I Google, there was some indications that doing selection/copy multiple times made the problem more noticable.  That was why I was asking you to copy it multiple times since I am having to copy multiple rows...

Comment: Can't you give us an MCVE so we don't have to play this guessing game.

Comment: Unfortunately not without you having the Add In Express library, as that is what does all the interfacing with Excel.  I need to contact them to see what I am doing wrong.  Thanks though...

Comment: I explained that I was copying multiple rows (`A1:X44`, which is 44 rows inclusive with 26 columns per row) in a single operation. Looping to repeat it is simply an exercise in futility. I give up, because you're not listening anyway. :-) Good luck.

Comment: I use add in express. It doesn't get in the way. It doesn't provide an extra layer over excel. You could make an mcve. If you want help from us you would do so.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  The issue WAS related to the "Picture too large.  Will be truncated" error when closing Excel.  The code I posted works fine.  Googling shows many issues with TeamViewer.  I uninstalled TeamViewer and this did NOT fix my error. I had to re-install it, then go to options/Advanced, and turn off Clipboard synchronization, then stop/restart Teamviewer.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help solve this, particularly Ken White.